# NodeJS unstable: unable to npm-install modules that need compilation

Tags: node.js, gyp

i've been working with NodeJS 0.11.x distros for some time now, mainly because i believe that generators and the `yield` statement bring big advances in terms of asynchronous manageability (see [coffy-script](https://github.com/loveencounterflow/coffy-script) and [suspend](https://github.com/loveencounterflow/coffeenode-suspend)).

that said, there's a serious setback when running bleeding-edge, unstable NodeJS installs: when doing `npm install xy-module`, `gyp` will fail (always? sometimes?) when trying to compile any C components.

is there a general reason this must be so? is there any trick / patch / configuration i can apply to remedy the situation? if a given module does compile on NodeJS 0.10.x, but fails on 0.11.x, should i expect it to compile on 0.12.x as soon as that becomes available?

**Update** i cross-posted the issue on the NodeJS mailing list, and [ben noordhuis was kind enough to share some details](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/nodejs/j_EpLdSbFSU/5yA2EvfBtUQJ). quoting his message:

The two main changes are as follows:

- `Persistent<T>` no longer derives from `Handle<T>`.  To recreate the
  Handle from a Persistent, call `Local<T>::New(isolate, persistent)`.
  You can obtain the isolate with `Isolate::GetCurrent()` (but note that
  `Isolate::GetCurrent()` will probably go away in newer versions of V8.)
- The prototype of C++ callbacks and accessors has changed.  Before,
  your function looked like this:

  ```
  Handle<Value> MyCallback(const Arguments& args) {
    HandleScope handle_scope;
    /* Do useful work, then: */
    return handle_scope.Close(Integer::New(42));
    /* Or: */
    return handle_scope.Close(String::New("hello"));
    /* Or: */
    return Null();
  }
  ```

  In v0.11 and v0.12 that becomes:

  ```
  void MyCallback(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
    Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
    HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);
    /* Do useful work, then: */
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(42);
    /* Or: */
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "hello"));
    /* Or: */
    args.GetReturnValue().SetNull();
  }
  ```

There have been more changes but these two impact every native add-on.

Comment: Folks should build their modules in pure js, setting up windows to compile is a ridiculous effort.  Had to be said.

Comment: i'm all for this—requiring a compile step adds one more point of failure to software. in the (very interesting) podcast referred to by @rvagg below they say not everything can be done in pure JS (yet), and there may be speed benefits (but i see those diminishing)

Comment: Best example I have is websockets.  Socket.io needs compile and I'm not going through a hour long set of instructions when I can use https://github.com/einaros/ws   I would probably argue that performance or capability of certain advanced things in Node, which it's debatable these are really necessary anyway, should be addressed in Node, or maybe Node isn't the right platform and you should be using C/C++.  Cross-platform is one of the great things about Node and should be preserved IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in detail in NodeUp #52: http://nodeup.com/fiftytwo

Summary: major changes in the v8 API, some minor changes in Node, and the changes are still ongoing. But there are two projects that are designed to help with the problem, NAN (github/rvagg/nan) and shim / node-addon-layer (github/tjfontaine/node-addon-layer).

Comment: at some suitable point in time it would be great if NAN could be pushed to make it as popular as NPM so we can get more durable native modules in NodeJS.